# Find and replace over multiple lines in a huge text file

Tags: regex, logging, text, replace, find

I've got a huge log file (almost 6 GB) of a game server filled with millions of errors (hundreds were caused every second at that time) besides useful records that need to be kept. I'd like to remove all the lines including an error while keeping the ones showing chat messages or other information.

However, I can't just easily remove the lines I'd like to dump because the error messages aren't always the same and always require a different amount of lines. In short, I simply can't determine which lines include an error. I need a regular expression to do so. I've been looking for a program that fits my purposes. I haven't found one yet, though. sed (stream editor) could do such a job for instance as it wouldn't need too many resources to process such a huge file. However, it doesn't support finding and replacing over multiple lines.

Therefore, is there a program that supports finding and replacing regular expressions in huge text files over multiple lines? Or is it recommended to write your own script to do that job?

The log file looks as follows:

```
2011-03-02 01:43:00 [INFO] <admin> CraftBook is causing errors. 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sk89q.worldedit.blocks.BlockType.isRedstoneBlock(I)Z
    at com.sk89q.craftbook.bukkit.MechanicListenerAdapter$MechanicBlockListener.onBlockRedstoneChange(MechanicListenerAdapter.java:174)
    at net.minecraft.server.BlockButton.a(BlockButton.java:170)
    at net.minecraft.server.ItemInWorldManager.a(ItemInWorldManager.java:160)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:482)
    at net.minecraft.server.Packet15Place.a(SourceFile:57)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.a(SourceFile:230)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:75)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(SourceFile:100)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(MinecraftServer.java:357)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:272)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:366)
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Is it working yet? 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Not really. 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sk89q.worldedit.blocks.BlockType.isRedstoneBlock(I)Z
    at com.sk89q.craftbook.bukkit.MechanicListenerAdapter$MechanicBlockListener.onBlockRedstoneChange(MechanicListenerAdapter.java:174)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(MinecraftServer.java:348)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:272)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:366)
2011-03-02 01:43:02 [INFO] <admin> I hope we find a solution as soon as ever possible.
```

The desired result would be the following:

```
2011-03-02 01:43:00 [INFO] <admin> CraftBook is causing errors.
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Is it working yet? 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Not really. 
2011-03-02 01:43:02 [INFO] <admin> I hope we find a solution as soon as ever possible.
```

As you can see, the log file contains the same error over and over again. Even though it always starts with the date and time followed by **[SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms** and ends with **at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:366)**, the error message in between is different each time. That's why I can't just replace the error message by an empty string.

Is there a regular expression that could both help me get rid of all the lines containing an error but keep the remaining lines? That way, my log file would shrink to under 50 MB in size as it used to be before all these errors were caused by my server due to a broken plugin.

Comment: Quick question (and maybe simplistic approach), would it be ok if you just keep the lines that contain the string `<admin>`?

Comment: No, the example above doesn't really show you all possible outputs of the server. Actually, the server may also write other stuff into the log file. The server also writes other errors on multiple lines into the server.log. I'd like to keep these errors. I just want to be able to get rid of the specific error mentioned in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Python script makes one pass through a logfile read from stdin, printing the filtered log messages to stdout.

It uses a regular expression to match lines that mark the beginning of a log message (such as a line that starts with `2011-03-02 01:43:00 [`).

If a line that begins a log message contains `[SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms`, the script discards all lines between that line and the line containing the start of the next log message.  Otherwise, it outputs the line.  You can think of this as a finite state machine with two states, which correspond to whether the script is skipping over lines or outputting lines.

```
import sys
import re

START_OF_MESSAGE_RE = r"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"
ERROR_RE = START_OF_MESSAGE_RE + r' \[SEVERE\] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms$'
skip_until_next_message = False

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.match(START_OF_MESSAGE_RE, line):
        if re.match(ERROR_RE, line):
            skip_until_next_message = True
        else:
            skip_until_next_message = False
    if not skip_until_next_message:
        print line
```

I added some special cases to the log file for testing.  Here's the log file that I tested it with:

```
2011-03-02 01:43:00 [INFO] <admin> CraftBook is causing errors. 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sk89q.worldedit.blocks.BlockType.isRedstoneBlock(I)Z
    at com.sk89q.craftbook.bukkit.MechanicListenerAdapter$MechanicBlockListener.onBlockRedstoneChange(MechanicListenerAdapter.java:174)
    at net.minecraft.server.BlockButton.a(BlockButton.java:170)
    at net.minecraft.server.ItemInWorldManager.a(ItemInWorldManager.java:160)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:482)
    at net.minecraft.server.Packet15Place.a(SourceFile:57)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkManager.a(SourceFile:230)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetServerHandler.a(NetServerHandler.java:75)
    at net.minecraft.server.NetworkListenThread.a(SourceFile:100)
    [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(MinecraftServer.java:357)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:272)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:366)
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Is it working yet? 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Not really. 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sk89q.worldedit.blocks.BlockType.isRedstoneBlock(I)Z
    at com.sk89q.craftbook.bukkit.MechanicListenerAdapter$MechanicBlockListener.onBlockRedstoneChange(MechanicListenerAdapter.java:174)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.h(MinecraftServer.java:348)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:272)
    at net.minecraft.server.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:366)
2011-03-02 01:43:02 [INFO] <admin> I hope we find a solution as soon as ever possible. 
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Another multi
line
log
message
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Here's the error: [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
```

And here's the output:

```
$ python minecraftlog.py < minecraft.log 
2011-03-02 01:43:00 [INFO] <admin> CraftBook is causing errors.
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Is it working yet?
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Not really.
2011-03-02 01:43:02 [INFO] <admin> I hope we find a solution as soon as ever possible.
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [SEVERE] Another multi
line
log
message
2011-03-02 01:43:01 [INFO] <admin> Here's the error: [SEVERE] Could not pass event REDSTONE_CHANGE to CraftBookMechanisms
```

Comment: Thank you for writing that Python script. It was surprisingly simple! In fact, it was able to process the whole file (6 GB) in only a minute. Afterwards, I just had to add the carriage returns that were removed by the Python script run on a Linux machine using a simple tr-command I found on the internet. Now I finally have got a clean log file that is 50 MB in size instead of the 6 GB it used to be including all the errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the better approach is to match the lines you want to keep, indirectly "removing" the lines you do not care about:

The following Perl script should suffice:

```
while (<>) {
  next unless /^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\[INFO\]/;
  print;
}
```

Comment: That would also be an approach. However, the server also outputs other stuff not shown in the example above. It may also write other errors into the server.log. I'd like to keep them and only get rid of the specific error mentioned in the example. Besides, not every line starts with the date and time. There are line breaks inside the information given. That's why you can't just match the lines I'd like to keep.

Comment: Then see Josh Rosen's answer, but I would have done something similar in Perl.  You basically echo the log input, but set a suppression flag if you match the first line of the error message you want to exclude.  Reenabling echoing when you get to next do-not-exclude log message.